# VBA for Powerpoint: Change Slide in One Powerpoint by Selecting Button in Another

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a beginner at VBA.

I am designing a somewhat interactive Powerpoint presentation/s. I want to be able to have three separate Powerpoint presentations open that will link together. I have been trying (without success) to create, in VBA, code which will change the current displayed slide on one Powerpoint file by clicking a button in another. I can hyperlink to the set slide but this causes this slide to pop up on the same screen in which it is clicked, despite it being already open in another screen (I don't want this).

Thanks in advance for any help, 
Holly

Comment: Would help if you [edit] your question with your current code, thanks!

Comment: I haven't really got any yet, I tried numerous things but as I said, beginner! I have experience in using other languages but finding the VBA syntax really confusing. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

VBA uses an object model that is a huge hierarchy of attributes and functions that represent the application. You can use this model to view and update attributes to get text, resize, and modify the application. You should look at some tutorials to get you started. When editing your code, you can press F2 to see and explore this object model. You can press F8 to run your code line by line (debug mode) and see what is happening. 
To your question, you can access the open presentations in the application.presentations object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentations). You could then use a presentation in that list and use the `ActiveWindow.View.goToSlide` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.view.gotoslide). Here is a free tutorial that I've used in my VBA journey (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/index.htm).

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks so much for replying. This is really useful and I had come across some of these functions when searching. I really need to get this done soon - any chance you would have a minute to put some example code together that I can try? Thanks again - Holly :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I came across this article for you that demonstrates how to link to other presentations that might not require any code or VBA at all (https://www.howtogeek.com/442559/how-to-link-from-one-powerpoint-presentation-to-another/).  And as a reminder stack overflow guidelines suggest that you post the code you've tried and seek help with it's implementation. We can't write it for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi again, sorry I didn't realise I had to post some code. I had attempted some but it wasn't working and as I have very little understanding of VBA I am really confused about what to write. I had seen this article but it sets it up so the new slide plays on the same screen as my original Powerpoint - I want it to change in the second and for the original one to stay intact.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint has a Presentations collection that contains all currently open presentations. You can get a reference to any of them via Presentations("name") where "name" is the filename of the presentation, sans extension.

So ... assuming you've got three presentations open, a.pptx, b.pptx, c.pptx you can do something like this:

```
Sub SlideChange()
    With Presentations("c")
        .SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (3)
    End With
End Sub
```

If you run the above in any of the presentations, it will change the slide show window displaying presentation c to the third slide.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works, I spent all day trying to do this at work!!!!